# How to set the URL path to integer

Tags: php, symfony

in my routing.yml

```
acme_tag_homepage:    
    pattern:  /tag/{page}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeTopBundle:Default:page:"1" }
```

page is supposed to have integer value.
However , if you put

```
/tag/aaa
```

it works.

It's not big problem though, if you put

```
/tag/index.html
```

it works and it's not good thing for search crawler.

How can I set the {page} value restrict to integer or numbers??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
acme_tag_homepage:    
    path:  /tag/{page}
    defaults: 
        _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Default:page
        page: 1 # if you want to provide a default value
    requirements:
        page: \d+
```